# Stop event for ng-keypress in angularjs bug in Android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

Android navigators not stop event.

```
 <input 
  type="text"
  name="folioId"
  ng-keypress="keypressOnFolioNumber($event)"
  ng-model="loginCredentials.folioId"
 required/>
```

On the controller

```
$scope.keypressOnFolioNumber = function ($event){
    //console.info($event);
    if ($event.charCode < 48 || $event.charCode > 57) {
        $event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
}
```

this code not working in Android navigators.

Comment: What do you mean by "this code not working"?  For instance, when someone presses it, does the phone explode?  Does a clown appear?  Are you teleported to a different dimension?

Comment: How to get keypress event in angular on Android?